# jQuery Mobile and jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Mobile and jQuery validate and having trouble getting it to work. Here is my code so far.

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    $("#page2 form").validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: "required",
            lastName: "required"
        },
    });
});
```

This doesn't work. I've also tried it just by including the validation without the on click event and that doesn't work either. Ideas?

**UPDATE: In case if anyone looks at this, the code is fine, I had an error in my markup. Still a great answer below by Sparky though.**

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors? What mobile device are you using?

Comment: No JavaScript errors, just testing on browsers for now. It needs to work on desktop and mobile. I just can't figure out why I can't get them to work. I've never had issues with the validate plugin before.

Comment: Your code is working as expected, as long as you initialize the plugin properly and get rid of the click handler: http://jsfiddle.net/6FYyv/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your code:**

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() { // <-- REMOVE this
    $("#page2 form").validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: "required",
            lastName: "required"
        },
    });
});
```

[`.validate()` should only used *one time* to *intialize* the form **on DOM ready**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options).  It makes no sense to enclose the initialization of a plugin within a click handler.   The plugin already has all the event handlers built into it that will trigger the actual validation tests.

plain jQuery example: http://jsfiddle.net/RmG2g/

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#page2 form").validate({ ... });
});
```

---

**HOWEVER, since you're using jQuery Mobile**:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){ // <-- you must use this to ensure the DOM is ready

    $("#page2 form").validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: "required",
            lastName: "required"
        },
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/6FYyv/**

---

For jQuery Mobile, you'll need to use....

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

See:   http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

> **Important:** Use `$(document).bind('pageinit')`, not `$(document).ready()`
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   `$(document).ready()` function so everything will execute as soon as
>   the DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the `pageinit` event.

Comment: Thanks, the on click was experimentation out of desperation, my issue turned out to be faulty markup in the end, but the on pageinit is greatly helpful as I have now switched all my javascript into pageinit instead of document ready.

Comment: @IanHoar, Glad I could help.  For the readers' benefit, just to reiterate, the `pageinit` event is only for use as long as `jQuery Mobile` is included.